# SLD polygon styling + labeling in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I'm trying to label a polygon alongside its boundary. I found out how to do it but the stroke color of the polygon looks wear because of a black line above it. I think that the step I use to label the boundary of the polygon instead of the polygon itself generate also a small polyline which I cannot manipulate. I'd like to make this black polyline disappear or at least to give it a color like my polygon stroke.

```
    <Rule>
      <Name>Zone 100m</Name>
      <Title>Zone 100m</Title>
     <ogc:Filter>        
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>ToBufDist</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>       
      <PolygonSymbolizer>         
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>          
      <TextSymbolizer>         
      <Geometry>
        <ogc:Function name="boundary">                                                                                   
        <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        </ogc:Function>               
      </Geometry>          
        <Label>
        <ogc:PropertyName>Project</ogc:PropertyName>          
        </Label>            
        <LabelPlacement>
            <LinePlacement/>
        </LabelPlacement>
         <Halo>
            <Radius>3</Radius>
            <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
        </Halo>         
        <Fill>
            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
        </Fill> 
        <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>            
      </TextSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

Sorry, forgot to post a picture
[image: in this picture I made the 100m boundary bigger to show the small black line]

Comment: can you add a picture of what your output looks like

Comment: I also tryed to add a <LineSymbolizer> in different places (after the Geometry, after the Fill, ...) but I always get an error that something else is expected there.

Comment: I don't think that line is caused by that Rule - can you try deleting all the other rules (in a test SLD) and see if it is still there

Comment: you are right Ian, there was another rule i didn't see (I inherited the SLD!) wich defined all the rest of the values to have a black boundary. But now I have an issue with the ElseFilter. Is this the right way to use the Else statement? <Rule>
        <Name>Others</Name>
          <Title>Others</Title>
         <ogc:ElseFilter>
         </ogc:ElseFilter>         <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>

Comment: please use the ask question button to post a new question